# KoGrid JSON Dynamic widgets, with nested server calls

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on a dashboard where I am using KOGrid, my idea is to dynamically create a bunch of widgets and bind data into the kogrid for each widget. I have two controllers (MVC4), where the fist returns a list of widget names and the second returns results (datatable) for each widget in JSON format. I am using JSON.Net JsonConvert to convert the results to json format then passing as JSON content result.

I am getting  "Uncaught Error: The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined". 
Is it the nested JSON calls a problem? What is the most reliable way to handle Arrays of complex objects and binding them to multiple grids. Does it help if I use knockout.mapping?

var widgets = {};

```
var Widget = function (id, data) {
    this.id = ko.observableArray(id || []);     
    this.data = ko.observableArray(data || []);
};

var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.widgets = ko.observableArray(
                        ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (i) {
                            return new Widget(i);
                        }));

    $.getJSON('Widgets/Get', null, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $.getJSON('Home/GetWidgetDetails?widgetName=' + item.WIDGET_NAME,
                    function (result) {
                        self.widgets.push(new Widget({ id: item.WIDGET_NAME, data: result }));                            
                    });
        });
    });

};

 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(widgets));
```

Comment: The error was due to id being oservablearray instead of just observable. The error is gone after fixing it but I still don't see the grid populated, no idea what is wrong in the HTML below?
<div data-bind="foreach: widgets">
    <ul data-bind="attr: { id: id}, foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"> <div class="example" style="height: 300px; width: 600px;" data-bind="koGrid: { data: $data }></div> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are getting this error on the `data` prop in the `Widget` class? If so, then yes it is probably the JSON structure of the `data` array. If they are complex objects themselves, you should repeat the same process you did for Widgets.

1. Make an object definition for these items. Perhaps `WidgetItem`.
2. use `ko.utils.arrayMap` to map the `data` array onto `WidgetItem`.
3. Success.

Without seeing the structure of `data` though, I can't give you anything more specific.

Comment: Each widget is different, say one is customers and the other is orders. I have a generic MVC controller which accepts widget name and it will automatically identify the sql behind it, executes it and returns the results in JSON format (using newtonsoft JsonConvert). KOGrid is an awesome control to bind anything on its way but I think it is knockout which is blocking. I can share the code somewhere if that helps.

Comment: It might. But, regardless, if you want to place these different widgets in an observableArray, you are going to want to have a type that represents then. Try to figure out common properties, and maybe make some of the names generic enough to handle your different widgets. I can help you with this if you give me some concrete examples.

Comment: I fixed it. https://github.com/sergun/Knockout-MultiModels.         $.each(data, function (index, item) {var li = "<li id='" + item.WIDGET_NAME + "_li'></li>";div.append(li);
$("#" + item.WIDGET_NAME + "_li").append("<div data-model='" + item.WIDGET_NAME + "Tittle" + "'> <div id= '" + item.WIDGET_NAME + "' class='example' data-bind='koGrid: { data: myObsArray }'></div></div>"); 
$.getJSON('Home/GetWidgetDetails?widgetName=' + item.WIDGET_NAME,function (data) {ko.attach(item.WIDGET_NAME + "Tittle", {Title: ko.observable(item.WIDGET_NAME + "Tittle"),myObsArray: ko.observableArray(data) });});});